# NaN error in jquery. Have tried ParseInt, still not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

whats wrong with my code here??

```
var value = $('#qty').val() * $('#rate').val();
var tax =  value * $('#tax').val() / 100;
$('#valueshow').text(tax);
$('#value').val(value);
```

the html part is

```
<input type='text' name='qty"' size = '5'>
<input type='text' name='rate' size = '5'> 
<input type='text' name='tax' size = '5'> 
<input name='value' id='value'> 
<span id='valueshow'></span>
```

its giving NaN error..please help

Comment: Where are yo calling that JS code? What are the values that you get from the inputs?

Comment: hmmm.. using id selectors without an id for the elements.. I think you need to take a break :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your html code as

```
<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' size = '5'>
<input type='text' name='rate' id='rate' size = '5'> 
<input type='text' name='tax' id='tax' size = '5'> 
<input name='value' id='value'> 
<span id='valueshow'></span>
```

whenever you had used id's for the hyml elements then only you can use "#" as ('#qty').val()
hope you can use this

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/

Comment: oops...:D...now there is another issue. Do i need to have a OnChange event associated with it? Or JQuery will automatically calculate every time some value is input in the HTML? Because thats now happening as of now. –

Answer (score 4):

You have error in jquery code because jquery # use for id. In your code you does not apply Id in html input type so apply id and try it like

```
 $('#qty').val() 

<input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' size = '5'>
```

Comment: oops...:D...now there is another issue. Do i need to have a OnChange event associated with it? Or JQuery will automatically calculate every time some value is input in the HTML? Because thats now happening as of now.

Comment: Means you have call onchange event of textbox?

Comment: No I dont have any event yet of now..my code is all that I posted, because I thought it should automatically calculate value and tax based on values input in the qty and rate. But thats not happening. Do I need onChange event, so that everytime there is a change in qty or tax, the function is called to calculate tax and value??

Comment: So you have write keypress function for qty and rate